# How to display the contents of the xml document retrieved from the jquery.ajax()...?

Tags: web-services, jquery

I am invoking a web service through $.ajax(). 
onsuccess I am getting an xml document, now the problem is I need to see the contents of the retrieved xmlDocument..

Is there anyway to do that.. ??

Comment: where do you plan to show the documents? in a page? or do you just want to read it? you can print it out in console.log if you just want to read it manually

Comment: do you just want to see the result of the ajax call? Consider using Firefox with the Firebug add-on. It makes web development much easier.

Comment: can you show the sample xml you are receiving

Comment: @corroded: i just want to see the entire xml document returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it to the textarea field as-is

```
$("#textareaID").val(xmlstr);
```

or display with html-encoding:

```
$("#someDivID").text(xmlstr); // jQuery text() function performs html-encoding automatically
```

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wKhnF/1/

Note `dataType: "text"`, it is required to process the response contents as a text rather then XML object.

Comment: success: function(data,testStatus){ alert($.parseXML(data)); } 
here i am getting an alert showing [object:object]

Comment: change `dataType` to `text` as described, not `xml`

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebug to check the response.

You can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ to read, parse the XML, find, and retrieve elements.

```
$.parseXML(xml)
```

Comment: success: function(data,testStatus){
alert($.parseXML(data));
}
here i am getting an alert showing [object:object]

Comment: thats an javascript object and you need to read through the elements you want to handle.

Comment: the problem is i dont know what kind of response the web service is sending.... i only know that it is an xml object ... so i want to know  what is there inside the xmlDocument... is that possible .. ?????

Comment: Possible. Use firebug addon to check the response of your ajax requests on browser. It will display the xml. Or check for the solution mentioned by Artem.